# Buscador que busque por Fecha en asp.net core mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp, asp.net-core

Tengo un buscador que busca por tipo de dato `string`, pero a la hora de agregarle la busqueda de una variable de tipo de dato `DateTime`, me da el siguiente error:

> Decimal does contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'AsyncEnumerable.Contains(IAsincEnumerable , string)
>   requires a receiver of type 'IAsyncEnumerable''

Este es mi codigo en el controlador:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( string sortOrder,
                                                string currentFilter,
                                                string searchString,
                                                int? page)
        {
            ViewData["PrecioSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Precio_desc" : "";
            ViewData["FecFinSortParm"] = sortOrder == "FecFin_asc" ? "FecFin_desc" : "FecFin_asc";



            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;


            var PreCombusts = from s in _context.PreCombust select s;


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                PreCombusts = PreCombusts.Where(s => s.Precio.Contains(searchString) || s.FecFin.Contains(searchString));
            }


            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Precio_desc":
                    PreCombusts = PreCombusts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Precio);
                    break;
                case "FecFin_desc":
                    PreCombusts = PreCombusts.OrderByDescending(s => s.FecFin);
                    break;


                case "FecFin_asc":
                    PreCombusts = PreCombusts.OrderBy(s => s.FecFin);
                    break;
                default:
                    PreCombusts = PreCombusts.OrderBy(s => s.Precio);
                    break;
            }



 var applicationDbContext = _context.PreCombust.Include(p => p.Combustibles);
            return View(await PreCombusts.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());


    }
```

si me pueden ayudar y decirme alguna forma para poder buscar por fecha les agradeceria mucho!!

Answer (score 2):

El error lo que indica es que estas utilizando el metodo `Contains(string)` sobre un tipo de datos `System.Decimal` y este tipo de dato hasta la fecha no tiene tal metodo.

Asi que tendras que convertir el valor de `decimal` a `String`.

Intenta cambiando de:

```
s.Precio.Contains(searchString) || s.FecFin.Contains(searchString)
```

A:

```
s.Precio.ToString().Contains(searchString) || s.FecFin.ToString().Contains(searchString)
```

El metodo `ToString()` convierte los valores decimal a `String`:

Comment: Resuelto el problema!!! Thankssssss! @Einer